# openBugs error with expected a comma or right parenthesis. where is my mistake?

Tags: winbugs, openbugs

list(cases=structure(.Data =c(1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA),.Dim = c(5,12)), x1=structure(.Data=c(1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01),.Dim = c(5,12)),x2=structure(.Data =c(1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01), .Dim = c(5,12)),x3=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),  w1=c(1.00000E+00, 2.00000E+00, 1.00000E+00, 1.00000E+00, 2.00000E+00),w2=structure(.Data =c(1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01),.Dim = c(5,12)),z=structure(.Data =c(1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 1.20000E+01, 1.10000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 2.30000E+01, 2.20000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01, 3.40000E+01, 3.30000E+01),.Dim = c(5,12)),
s=5,t=12,
adj=c(
2,4,
1,3,
2,4,
1,3,5
4),
num=c(2,2,2,3,1),sumNumNeigh=10)

Answer (score 0):

Towards the end there's a space without a comma between the `5` and `4`: `adj=c( 2,4, 1,3, 2,4, 1,3,5 4)`.